# How can I hide a category in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following list of categories:

```
id | name
-------------
1  | Flash 
2  | port
3  | Weather
4  | Capital
5  | BBC
```

I want to skip the `BBC` category from the following `while` loop:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 20");
while ($news = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    //news code
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can achieve it in many ways. What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Also, don’t use `mysql_query` and other `mysql_` functions: they’re **deprecated**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
while ($news = mysql_fecth_object($sql)) {
    if ($news->id === 5) { 
        continue;
    }

    // process $news
}
```

Or

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id <> 5 LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: It means not equal to. You could also do `!=` instead.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal